enable TailwindCSS preflight only within some div
I'm converting established project with bunch of CSS to Tailwind. Therfore I must disable Tailwind preflight (a.k.a reset defaults on elements)  with corePlugins: { preflight: false},
Now when I'm styling new elements with TW my elements have old CSS defaults (e.g. <p> has 1em margin bottom)
I was wondering if there is a feature in Tailwind that would allow me to enable prefilight element settings within certain div. For example
<p>Old CSS paragraph with 1em margin bottom</p>

<div class="preflight-enabled">
  <p>TW preflights kick in and this paragraph has 0 margin bottom</p>
</div>


Note: I'm refactoring component by component rather than whole page at once (e.g relpacing navbar but content stays the same), so I cannot just  preflight reset in  for given page
Thank you ♥️

There is no such feature built into Tailwind's preflight plugin. However, you could consider disabling preflight (as you have already done) and then adapting the core's preflight version in a Tailwind plugin that "scopes" the selectors, like:
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
const postcss = require('postcss');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // …
    },
  },
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(({ addBase }) => {
      // Read the "base" preflight CSS file, like what core preflight does.
      const styles = postcss.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(
          require.resolve('tailwindcss/lib/css/preflight.css'),
          'utf8',
        ),
      );

      // Walk through each CSS rule, modifying them to our needs:
      styles.walkRules((rule) => {
        // Iterate through each CSS selector for a rule (selectors that
        // are separated by a comma (,).
        rule.selectors = rule.selectors.map((selector) =>
          // These high level elements won't ever exist in our use case.
          // So for these:
          ['html', ':host', 'body'].includes(selector)
            // Replace the selector entirely with our scoping class.
            ? '.preflight-enabled'
            // Or otherwise, prefix the scoping class. We use `:where()`
            // so that the selector specificity remains unaffected and is
            // a maximum of (0, 1, 0). This is so that utility classes
            // that typically have a minimum specificity of (0, 1, 0)
            // will still be able to override these preflight rules as
            // necessary.
            : ':where(.preflight-enabled) ' + selector,
        );
      });

      // Register in the style nodes, like what core preflight does.
      addBase(styles.nodes);
    }),
  ],
};

Thus, you'll end up with scoped CSS:
:where(.preflight-enabled) blockquote,
:where(.preflight-enabled) dl,
:where(.preflight-enabled) dd,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h1,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h2,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h3,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h4,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h5,
:where(.preflight-enabled) h6,
:where(.preflight-enabled) hr,
:where(.preflight-enabled) figure,
:where(.preflight-enabled) p,
:where(.preflight-enabled) pre {
  margin: 0;
}

Going further
You could optimize this better by wrapping the selectors in :where() or :is() to reduce the repetition like:
:where(.preflight-enabled) :is(
  blockquote,
  dl,
  dd,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6,
  hr,
  figure,
  p,
  pre
) {
  margin: 0;
}

Though you'd need to account for pseudo-elements (like ::before and ::after) that can't be inside :where() or :is(). You'd need to have some extra logic to scan for the rule's selectors and be able to intelligently wrap them as necessary.
